# Is appending element faster than replacing in Python?

Tags: python

I got my first problem handed to me on leet code which was about making a Fibonacci sequence function. This was my submission below. As some of you may notice I come from MATLAB background and I think they always define a matrix first.

I looked at other solutions after solving this and noticed that most of fast solution went for appending. Mine wasn't slow but I was curious. As my title suggests is it more efficient to append in Python?

```
class Solution(object):
    def runningSum(self, nums):

        newnums=nums[0:]

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            newnums[i]=sum(nums[:i+1])

        return(newnums)
```

Comment: That's not Fibonacci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a long list whose length is known in advance, it should be somewhat beneficial to create the list first (as you do), because the repeated appending will have to resize and copy the underlying array every now and then.
What makes your approach quadratic is the repeated summing of the entire list prefix when you have the previous sum readily available in the previous cell of your result:

```
class Solution:
    def runningSum(self, nums):
        newnums = nums[:]  # shallow copy
        for i in range(1, len(nums)):
            newnums[i] += newnums[i-1]  # just add prev cell
        return newnums
```

Also, Leetcode is usually quite liberal with modifying their input data. They don't check if you mutate them, so even the simpler

```
class Solution:
    def runningSum(self, nums):
        for i in range(1, len(nums)):
            nums[i] += nums[i-1]  # just add prev cell
        return nums
```

works. Both are linear in time complexity but you save the effort of creating a new list. And once you get into Leetcode specifics, you can make use of the fact that they have all the `itertools` imported, `accumulate` in particular is useful here:

```
class Solution:
    def runningSum(self, nums):
        return [*accumulate(nums)]
```

Or as cleverly suggested in the comments:

```
class Solution:
    runningSum = accumulate
```

which only works when choosing Python3 as your interpreter in which case you are kind of violating the type-annotation as this returns a lazy iterator and its acceptance depends strongly on the implementation of the tests.

Comment: I doubt the first sentence. The resizing is rare and very fast very low level work. I suspect it's insignificant and it's more about whether calling the append method is slower or faster than working with indices. I suspect it's faster, but would have to measure.

Comment: Since you're talking about taking advantage of LeetCode specifics... This also gets accepted: `class Solution: runningSum = accumulate`

Comment: I know, but that hurts since you then truly violate the type-annotated return type =)

Comment: append-solution looks about [twice as fast](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZLNasMwDMdht-UpdHTaJNTdZRT6FD2GEEJrd4ZYNv5g7Fl26WV7qD3NrGRZUsiYTrL0l_yT0PunfQsvBm-3jxhk-fz18HjuO-_hZPoYlMFDBskuQoKLiAqvp6g586KXBWDUPh8FZCheKQLHIVEfmt-MNA4UKATX4VUwXkAvkA3li_pFj1o1sD3Or5LPzZwI0eGUW8Hb_4dXz8181CmwuyNNKmIl8T0cibfDdGvMVWetwAtLqvwv2ExGPBPCtF6WV4u9FuvxfapzRkNQWoDS1rgw-Nk0D29gA3xHltEEkvjHrzbwREOEJKMSRmhyXH3yrFMY2JiAEkIBsmpb7LRo23y8iJ_DmA7kGw).